# Ajax calling PDO function in PHP class to update a page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, pdo

I have a list of files and a drop down box, I'd like the user to be able to filter them by various categories etc.

I have a php class that has the function for creating the sql query and returning the result.  I'd very much like to do this via ajax to prevent a refresh.

I'm stuck and was hoping for some help.

The problem is that I don't know what to do next.  This is pretty new to me but still plenty foreign.  If the ajax call can be run onKeyUp from the select then even better.

Thank you for any help:

the HTML:

```
<div>
  <form action="" method="post" name="orderBy">
    <label for="orderBy" id="orderBy">Order By:</label>
    <select>
      <option class="orderByOption" value="newest">Newest First</option>
      <option class="orderByOption" value="oldest">Oldest First</option>
      <option class="orderByOption" value="cat">Category</option>
      <option class="orderByOption" value="alpha">Aphabetical</option>
      <option class="orderByOption" value="fileType">Filetype</option>
    </select>
    <label> &nbsp; </label>
    <input type="submit" class="orderByTrainingButton" name="submit" value="Go!"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

The Ajax:

```
//form for changing the ordering of items in training all docs
$(function(){
    $(".orderByTrainingButton").click(function(){
        //validate and process
        //get vlaue
        var option = $(".orderByOption").val();


        var params = {option: option};

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "../trainingOrderByAjax.php",
            data: params,
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(data){

                if(data.success == true){
                    //aaaannnd. stuck/
                }else{
                    // shouldn't ge there...I hope.

                }

            },
            error: function( error ) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The php the ajax will call:

```
<?php

include_once('core/init.php');

if($_POST){
  $orderBy = $_POST['orderByOption'];

  if($training->getAlFilesOrderBy($orderBy)){
    $data['success'] = true;
  }else{
    $data['success'] = false;
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

To start with ordering by desc or asc would be great.  I can then build on that.

Comment: You're only passing `option` key data. You could always use `$("#myForm").serialize()` as your `data` parameter.

Comment: @HalfCrazed - what other data should I be passing?  That's all I need for the function parameter.  What might the benefits of serialize be and how could that fit in?

Comment: Considering you're using this: `$orderBy = $_POST['orderByOption'];` but you are not posting `orderByOption`...

Comment: @HalfCrazed - good spot :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

PHP:

```
if($results = $training->getAlFilesOrderBy($orderBy)){
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['results'] = $results;
}else{
    $data['success'] = false;
}
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

JS:

```
    if(data.success){
        var results = data.results;
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            // do something with results[i]
        }
    }else{
        // shouldn't ge there...I hope.
    }
```

Change your AJAX error handler to:

```
error: function(xhr, status, errorMsg) {
    console.log("AJAX error: " + errorMsg);
}
```

Comment: I don't think I'm calling the Ajax properly, nothing seems to be occurring when I check the console.  Just outputted result[i] but nothing is showing.

Comment: I'm assuming that `getAlFilesOrderBy()` returns the results as an array. I also assume that "Al" instead of "All" is intentional, not a typo. The AJAX call looks OK to me.

Comment: Hi Barmar, yes, it returns fetchAll.  typos love me...

I just amended the ajax somewhat to see where it was getting to. It doesn't get into the success part of the function.  Console says nothing other than Object.

$.ajax({
        success: function(data){
            alert("I don't display - assume ajax call failed?");
            if(data.success == true){
                alert("I'm shy...");
            }
            
        },
        error: function( error ) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    })

Comment: Check your PHP error log to see if the script is getting errors. I don't see an error in the snippet you posted, but there could be errors elsewhere in the script.

Comment: Tried the erroe log. "AJAX error: " is displayed but nothing else.

Comment: Maybe something helpful can be found in the Network tab of the javascript console.

Comment: Ive been through with a toothcomb but can't spot anything.  The value in the parm before the ajax call is correct.  I placed an alert out the ajax and thats ok.  I tried a vardump of the php variable but nothing was displayed.  I did notice using the safari debugger (using both :)) that on my other ajax call the php that it calls is displayed in the list of files but this one isn't

Comment: finally...progress: AJAX error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: Your script must be printing something before `echo json_encode(...)`.

Comment: call to undefined method now although I've included it in the init file.  Doens't make a great deal of sense.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be "getAllFilesOrderBy" -- with two `l`s in `All`?

Comment: BOLLOX!!!! when you mentioned the typo.  I adjusted it in the php.  the typo wasn't in the php, it was in the class.